# How to check that my network settings are suitable

Tags: windows-10, networking, network-shares

I look at the properties for my C: drive in Windows 10 and it says that it is shared in the network.

[image]

It also appears if I browse the network

[image]

I don't remember sharing the C drive and I don't know why it is shared. Should I check my settings or could there be a network security issue? I don't think there is a breach but I don't expect to see that the C drive is shared like this. I could try and see if I can break in from another computer in the same network, or do you see that I should make some change? It also says that there are two networks connected, one private network and one public network and that sharing with password is on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `C` drive is shared, then someone has shared it and depending on the share permissions they set, they or anyone accessing your network may be able to read, modify or delete any of your files on the `C` drive.

You can look at the sharing permissions if you drill further into that dialog. This may tell you more about who set it up, so you may wish to do this before removing it.

In general though, yes, it is a serious security issue to have a folder shared that can contain sensitive data, let alone the whole drive. If you are in charge of the computer, then you should remove the share. For good measure you should then reboot your computer, to ensure any existing connections are broken and no cached settings remain. Then, since there may have been malicious actions taken by an attacker, you should scan for malware and viruses.

You should also consider what the implications are (if any) of someone having knowledge of the files on your computer, and take any necessary actions to mitigate the consequences (such as cancelling credit cards if you believe your bank security details may have been made known).

Comment: I have removed the share but I don't think there was a breach because nothing happened. But I would like to see how and why it was shared. I search in the event log for any detail but there is nothing I can find in the event log about the share.

Comment: I think it might have been Docker issue as described in this https://forums.docker.com/t/c-drive-is-shared-with-the-network-unexpected/9113